# Installing MS SQL 2005 drivers for IIS 7.5 .NET apps

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005, iis-7

I don't normally do .NET development but I have a small .NET app that I need to set up on a new Win2K8 IIS 7.5 server, the SQL 2005 server is on a different box.  I've tested the .NET app on an Win7 IIS 7/SQL 2005 machine and it works fine.  When I run the app on the new server I get the following error:

```
The 'SQLNCLI11' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

I googled the error and found out that I needed to install the native client drivers.  I found the sqlncli.msi file on the database server and installed it on the IIS server.  Same problem.
I then installed the SQL Management Studio thinking that might have some drivers that it needed.  Same error.  I can connect through the management studio but the .NET app keeps giving me the same error.

Any suggestions?

Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the provider in my connection string from SQLNCLI11 to SQLNCLI10.

Works like a charm.